# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_color' in turtle module in python 3.8

Tags: python

The second piece of code work just fine, but the new one keeps throwing me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_color'
```

Any idea on why this error is being thrown?

```
# newcode
player.color('blue')
player.shape('triangle')
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(0,-250)
player.setheading(90)

# my other piece of code
padA = turtle.Turtle()
padA.speed(0)
padA.shape('square')
padA.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
padA.color('white')
padA.penup()
padA.goto(-350, 0)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see what the type of player is - it looks like it’s a `str` but I’m guessing it should be something else. You can find out by running `type(player)`

Comment: what do you mean by what type?

Comment: so everything in python has a type - for example ‘someword’ is a type of `str.` Here’s an article with a more in depth explanation: https://realpython.com/python-data-types/. In your particular case, you should try and print player and see what comes out or find out it’s type. If it is of type `str` then  str doesn’t have a color attribute and you would need to look at how `player` gets created.

Comment: I tried it in my Python idle, it says class 'type'

Comment: Oh, thank you for the help, I figured it out, it was because there was a missing bracket after the 'player = turtle.Turtle'